# Background not loading in firefox or internet explorer

Tags: html

in my website , https://naomirison.github.io/coffee-website/
 the  background does not appear and neither does my nav

chrome loads it fine attached is screen shot of what it looks like on chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tva3.jpg

Comment: What does your F12 console's Network tab say?

Comment: Questions asking about why code isn't working must include the code here, in the question itself (including HTML/CSS). The reason is simple: if we go off-site to look at yours, and then come back and post an answer which you use to fix your site, your question becomes useless to future readers - the problem no longer exists for them to use to see if it's similar to their problem, because you've fixed it. This site isn't designed to help just the person asking the question, but to build a knowledge base for future users. Without code here, your question does not help toward that goal.

Comment: here is a small part of  CSS code:                                                                                                body{
 font-size: 21px;
 color: $text-color;
 background:url(http://www.wallpapers-web.com/data/out/53/4184830-coffee-cup-wallpapers.jpg) center center;
 
 height: 1000px;
 
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;

}

Comment: I tried creating an image folder and linking that to the background url property, but image still did not show up

Answer (score 0):

When i look at [Http Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NII1E.png) for the resources that are loaded i see 301 http response for the background image which is referred using this URL:

http://www.wallpapers-web.com/data/out/53/4184830-coffee-cup-wallpapers.jpg

This means the image is no longer available at defined url path and has moved to some other path. Also if you hit this image url in browser it redirects to an html page, probably you need the right path to image. It is better to include the image as part of your application resources and refer locally.